# I'm encountering an issue where the formData object appears to be empty or not containing the expected data

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
const regSubmitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!slideScreen) {
        if (selectedFile.termsContidions === true) {
            if (selectedFile.signature !== "") {
                 setCheckValidation("");
                 const panRegex = /^(?=.{1,10}$)[A-Z]{5}[0-9]{1,4}[A-Z]{1}$/;
                 if (!panRegex.test(selectedFile.panNumber)) {
                     setCheckValidation("Please enter a valid PAN number");
                     setTimeout(() => {
                         setCheckValidation("");
                         5000);
                     return;
                     }
                 const loginUserData = JSON.parse(
                    sessionStorage.getItem("loginUserData")
                    );
                 const leadUserId = loginUserData?.lmsId;
```

Make the API request to check if PAN number already exists

```
 const queryParams = `?pan=${encodeURIComponent(
           selectedFile.panNumber
           )}&leadUserId=${encodeURIComponent(leadUserId)}`;
 const apiUrl = `${Api_Base_Url}/register/checkexistpan${queryParams}`;
 fetch(apiUrl, {
     method: "GET",
     headers: {
               "Content-Type": "application/json",
             },
           })
             .then((response) => response.json())
             .then((result) => {
```

Check if PAN number already exists

```
 if (result.success === false) {
     setCheckValidation("PAN Number already registered");
     setTimeout(() => {
     setCheckValidation("");
     5000);
     return;
 else {
     const formData = new FormData();
     formData.append("panNumber", selectedFile.panNumber);
     formData.append("address", selectedFile.address);
     formData.append("panCard", selectedFile.panCard);
     formData.append("aadharCard", selectedFile.aadharCard);
     formData.append("cheque", selectedFile.cheque);
     formData.append("signature", selectedFile.signature);
     const loginUserData = JSON.parse(
         sessionStorage.getItem("loginUserData")
                 );
     formData.append("leadUserId", loginUserData?._id || "");
     if (isProductMF === true) {
         let arnCheckBox = document.getElementsByClassName("arnCheck");
         arnCheckBox = Array.from(arnCheckBox);
         if (!arnCheckBox[0].checked === !arnCheckBox[1].checked) {
             setBlankInputFileds(true);
             return;
         else {
            setBlankInputFileds(false);
                   }
       formData.append("arnNumber", selectedFile.arnNumber);
                 }
       if (pdfBlob) {
           formData.append("pdfFile", pdfBlob, 'agreement.pdf');
                 }
       setNewFormData(formData);
 
 
       const signatureUrl = URL.createObjectURL(
          selectedFile.signature
                 );
       setSignatureUrl(signatureUrl);
```

Move to the slide screen

```
 setSlideScreen(true);
               }
             })
             .catch((error) => {
```

Handle error

```
 console.error(error);
             });
 else {
 setCheckValidation("Please upload your signature");
 setTimeout(() => {
 setCheckValidation("");
 5000);
         }
 else {
 setCheckValidation("Please accept terms & conditions");
 setTimeout(() => {
 setCheckValidation("");
 5000);
       }
     }
   }
```

I want to collect all the form data and pass it to a `FormData` object to use in an API request. However, I'm facing some challenges in achieving this.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).